# Remove button is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add preview and delete option before uploading multiple images, this is what I found:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
      var files = e.target.files,
        filesLength = files.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
        var f = files[i]
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
          var file = e.target;
          $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
            "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
            "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Remove image</span>" +
            "</span>").insertAfter("#files");
          $(".remove").click(function(){
            $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
          });            
        });
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
  }

});
```

But while uploading all images are getting uploaded, how to resolve this? I'm using php.

Comment: Try `$(document).on('click','.remove',function(){` instead of `$(".remove").click(function(){`. See if that works.

Comment: no it's not working...@Rasclatt

Comment: I guess I should clarify now, does the trigger work? If you put `console.log('test');` into that function before `$(this).parent(".pip").remove();` does it come up in the console?

Comment: Check if `this` has the value you think it does in your callback

Comment: As a side note: when you have 20 files at least one file will have 20 click-handlers attached to its remove button. You shouldn't attach click handler this generically over and over again. Bind it to the result of insertAfter instead.

Comment: @cepharum True that. Best to take it out of the loop.

Comment: @Rasclatt if I put `console.log('test')`, it's not showing preview or remove button, it simply gets uploaded....

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i'm create example that solved your problem:

**Your HTML**

```
<form method="post" id="sendForm">
  <input type="file" id="files" multiple>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Your JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
// Array which stores all selected images
var sendData = [];

$("#files").on("change", function(e) {
  var files = e.target.files,
    filesLength = files.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
    var f = files[i]
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
      var file = e.target;
      $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
        "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
        "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Remove image</span>" +
        "</span>").insertAfter("#files");
      // Add all images to array
      sendData.push({file: file, url: e.target.result});

      $(".remove").click(function() {
        var self = $(this).parent().children();
        sendData.map(function(value, currentIndex, data) {
          // Remove only image which removed from preview
          if (self[0].currentSrc === value.url) {
            sendData.splice(currentIndex, 1);
          }
        });
        $(this).parent().remove();
      });

      $("#sendForm").submit(function(e) {
        // Finally post all data to your PHP url that
        $.post("your/php/url", sendData);
      });
    });
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
});
  } else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
  }
});
```

Comment: It deletes all the images @Ivan

Comment: I changed to removing current image span. Please check it

Comment: Do you use the `multipart` attrubute on your input form? I created an example on `codepen.io` with your code and all works great. Please look at this [link](https://codepen.io/Stemy/pen/jLagRb)

Comment: It's removing only the previews but I'm asking how can I upload only the pictures that I've selected after deletion.....  I'm using php code to upload it...

Comment: yes I'm using multipart attribute `<form method="post" name="contentUpload" action="insertContent.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">` @Ivan

Comment: So you want to upload only one image or multiple? And do you want to select images which need to upload for example by click?

Comment: I'm uploading multiple images, and I want to upload only images after deletion. Like in this code if I select 3 images then it's showing 3 previews of the images with remove buttons, then if I delete one image then the preview is being removed but then if I upload it all 3 images are uploading.

Comment: in php from which field I should store the value?

Comment: This was my php code`<?php
include("connect.inc.php");
if(isset($_POST['btn_upload']))
{
 for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file_img']['name']); $i++)
{
 $filetmp = $_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"][$i];
 $filename = $_FILES["file_img"]["name"][$i];
 $filetype = $_FILES["file_img"]["type"][$i];
 $filepath = "photo/".$filename;
move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO upload_img (img_name,img_path,img_type) VALUES ('$filename','$filepath','$filetype')");
}
}

?>`

Comment: and this was my html code `<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file_img[]" multiple />
<input type="submit" name="btn_upload" value="upload" />
</form>`